# A hook as an array

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

There is this interface:

```
export interface msgX{
    user:any
    msg:any
    day:any
    time:any
  }
```

Then I define a hook array like this:

```
const [arrayMsg, setArrayMsg] =  useState <msgX> ( )
```

Because I get data from an API:

```
axios.get(url+"chat/"+props.ticket).then((resp: { data: any; }) => {
 for (let i=0; i<resp.data.length;i++){
     arrayMsg.push({user:resp.data[i].user,msg:resp.data[i].msg, day:resp.data[i].day, time:resp.data[i].time})
 }

})
```

But I can not make a push to that array hook.

I can not define a hook like this:

```
const [arrayMsg, setArrayMsg] =  useState <msgX> ([])
```

To do this:

```
axios.get(url+"chat/"+props.ticket).then((resp: { data: any; }) => {
 for (let i=0; i<resp.data.length;i++){
     array.push({user:resp.data[i].user,msg:resp.data[i].msg, day:resp.data[i].day, time:resp.data[i].time})
 }
setArrayMsg(array)
})
```

What can I do?

Comment: Have you tried `useState <msgX[]> ([]);`

Comment: Thanks. I must use to load the array setArrayMsg or arrayMsg.push?

Comment: You should avoid mutating the `arrayMsg`. So you should go with `setArrayMsg` and pass it a new array you created from the `resp.data`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first you need to change your state to this:

```
const [arrayMsg, setArrayMsg] = useState<msgX[]>([]);
```

and then change this:

```
axios.get(url + "chat/" + props.ticket).then((resp: { data: any }) => {
  setArrayMsg(
    resp.data.map((d) => ({
      user: d.user,
      msg: d.msg,
      day: d.day,
      time: d.time
    }))
  );
});
```